# Why is it that when I swap to landscape, my changes to the User Interface are undone?

Tags: java, android

I have another question!

I have a configure `Activity` in my app. On it, I have a `ListView`. Now adding & removing items to & from it works, but when I rotate the screen to landscape or back, all added & non-saved items in the `ListView` get removed... I wonder why this is... Why is this?

Comment: This has been answered lots of times already, please do a search before posting new questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When screen orientation changes, by default, the activity will be destroyed and create again. That means, the onCreate will be called again once the orientation changed. There are basically two way to solve your problem:

1. Save your activity state before destory and load it back when create
2. Set the Activity in [AndroidManifest](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#config) that not to handle screen orientation change.

E.g.

```
<activity name="..."
    android:configChanges="orientation" .../>
```

Comment: Is there a method I can override when the orientation changes?

Comment: onConfigurationChanged(). But normally you shouldn't save activity state there, better save when onPause() (which is a good practice as, for example, user pressed "home" key and leave your app, when he's back, your app still retain the state).

Comment: No, it must. onPause must be called prior to any onStop or onDestroy, see the diagram in http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html

Comment: and I mean if you go for the first option in my answer (not changing the manifest), whenever orientation change, it should go something like: onPause -> onStop -> onDestroy -> onCreate -> onResume

Answer (score 0):

When you rotate the handset, the `onStart` method of you Activity is invoked. Check maybe you do some sort of initialization there.

Comment: Your answer is a little unclear, as `onCreate` is called first, and then later `onStart`

Answer (score 0):

I've solved it partially. Now it is able to hold on to the changes when changing to landscape view, but not the other way back to the normal view. I did it through the use of `protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle saveState)`. But as I said, this doesn't work when it changes back from Landscape... Anybody got any ideas about this?